# HTML5 forms - semantic way of displaying errors from php validation

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm building a html5 form. To validate it at first I use html5 validate mechanisms (patterns, required, etc...), and then PHP server side validation. I'm writting it as a library, so I can't predict all possible cases.

For example, I've got email input:

```
<input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="you@domain.com" />
```

Now I'm checking with php if the domain: domain.com exists (* - see footnote).

If no, PHP render the form once more but should display error near the input that has validation mistakes.

**HOW TO DO THAT SEMANTICALY? What html element is good for it?**

I will give some wrong examples to ilustrate my problem (I will write only important fragments of code) :

```
<label for="mail">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" /> - given mail does not exist
```

Error without of html5 element. This is what I found to be most popular on websites, and most hopeless (stupid - no offense :) ) solution...

```
<label for="mail">Email (given mail does not exist):</label>
<input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" />
```

Is the error realy a label fragment? Or label is label, and error is not a fragment of label. In that case labels can be diferent (according to a given mail). Is this semantic?

```
<label for="mail">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" />       
<span class="error">Given mail does not exist</span>
```

No idea solution. Span can be used here, but this is another **no better idea** solution.

Another ideas:

- `<details>` - this isn't a detail...
- `<aside>` - this isn't aside, this is important!
- `<mark>`, `<strong>`, `<emph>` - with a given class?

Thanks for Your time and ideas. I know that even complicated error handling can be done using html5 validation methods, but there should be an object that is the best for showing such things in html5 semantic (for example for blind people - imagine the screen reader application, form filling by such a person by voice, and the first stupid solution usage. The screen reader should read whole page to hear just one error...)

Best regards

PS. If someone think, that there are better problems on earth (:D), yes of course there are. But we are those, who try to make the web more clean and available. And we really should take care about such details.

---

(*) which is not that easy in html5 You must use ajax, with php function, and override default Error handling mechanisms with Your own texts, and much much more...).

Comment: Maybe you think about this too much ?

Comment: Yeah. I read my question once more, and this is possible :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for an error message to be announced by assistive technology, it has to be associated with the field.  When a screen reader arrives on a form, it triggers what's known as "forms mode" and at that point it will only read out that which is associated with the fields themselves.

```
<label for="mail">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" aria-describedby="email_error" />       
<span class="error" id="email_error">Given mail does not exist</span>
```

In the above example, the use of `aria-describedby` allows you to create an explicit reference between the field and the error, which will ensure it is announced by screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

semantics are debatable; that said, the "stupid, no offense" example is the most semantic approach, except its better practice to wrap the message in a `span` element.
don't let that semantically lacking `span` fool you: this approach is for addressing accessibility support.
semantics are being used properly here, as this markup is displaying the correct information, its just not an audience that most people realize exists.
Read more about this technique here: [Simple inline error message pattern](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/01/simple-inline-error-message-pattern/)